# Spring Integration lock busy, another session is active

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm connecting to a POP3 inbox (it doesn't support IMAP, unfortunately) using Spring Integration. Here's my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

  <int:channel id="mailInputChannel"  />
  <int:channel id="channel1" />
  <int:channel id="channel2" />
  <int:channel id="discardChannel" />

  <!-- replace 'userid and 'password' with the real values -->
  <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
                      store-uri="pop3://userid:password@host.example.com/Inbox"
                  channel="mailInputChannel"
                  should-delete-messages="true"
                  auto-startup="true"
                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">

    <!-- Will poll every 1 seconds -->
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1000" fixed-delay="1000"/>

  </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int:recipient-list-router id="incomingMailRouter" input-channel="mailInputChannel">
    <int:recipient channel="channel1" selector-expression="payload.subject matches '^.*channel1.*$'"/>
    <int:recipient channel="channel2" selector-expression="payload.subject matches '^.*channel2.*$'"/>
  </int:recipient-list-router>      

  <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
  </util:properties>
</beans>
```

Basically I have an `inbound-channel-adapter` that reads in the messages and a simple `recipient-list-router` that directs it accordingly.

When I start up the application, it runs fine. However, after it processes the first email, it sometimes hangs. The debug output is:

```
19260 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.mail.Pop3MailReceiver  - connecting to store [pop3://username:password@mailhost.example.com/Inbox]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "mailhost.example.com", port 110, isSSL false
+OK Qpopper (version 4.0.5) at cobweb starting.  
CAPA
+OK Capability list follows
TOP
USER
LOGIN-DELAY 0
EXPIRE 0
UIDL
RESP-CODES
AUTH-RESP-CODE
X-MANGLE
X-MACRO
X-LOCALTIME Wed, 10 Aug 2016 11:50:57 -0700
IMPLEMENTATION Qpopper-version-4.0.5
.
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command failed
QUIT
+OK Pop server at cobweb signing off.
30529 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
30531 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel  - preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [IN-USE] /var/spool/maildrop/.program_name.pop lock busy!  Is another session active? (11), headers={id=43817279-7717-f4d7-971a-3c283e2dbec3, timestamp=1470849586452}]
30531 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  - _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [IN-USE] /var/spool/maildrop/.program_name.pop lock busy!  Is another session active? (11), headers={id=43817279-7717-f4d7-971a-3c283e2dbec3, timestamp=1470849586452}]
30534 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [IN-USE] /var/spool/maildrop/.program_name.pop lock busy!  Is another session active? (11)
  at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:131)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:209)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
  at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
  at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
  at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
  at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
  at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
  at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [IN-USE] /var/spool/maildrop/.program_name.pop lock busy!  Is another session active? (11)
  at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
  at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:286)
  at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:297)
  at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:319)
  at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:112)
  ... 19 more
```

It stays in this loop for a (seemingly) random amount of time, sometimes up to 2 minutes, spitting out these exceptions every time it tries to connect. However, sometimes it connects just file right after processing a message. Processing a message is the only thing that causes it to fail.

Is Spring trying to hold on to that connection to that connection too long? Can I tell it to drop the connection right after it fetches the email?

Comment: It should close the connection after each poll - have you tried setting `mail.debug` to `true` ?

Comment: @GaryRussell just did and updated the error log. Looks like the authentication command failed? Could it be something on the mail server's side?

Comment: That looks like the debug log from the session that failed; you need to look at the previous (successful) one and/or the server log (if any).

Comment: What should I be looking for? I found a line that says `+OK Pop server at cobweb signing off.` which makes me think it disconnected, but that output was right before it threw that exception. I set my logs to all output to `stdout`.

Comment: Right but two lines above it, it says `authentication failed` and the stack trace below says `AuthenticationFailedException: [IN-USE]  ... `. Which implies to me that the exception is thrown after the session is closed as a result of that authentication failure exception. You said this happens after "it runs fine". So I think you need to look to make sure the previous session terminated correctly; if it did then the finger points towards the server.

Comment: @GaryRussell Turns out it was a server-side issue. I switched to a different email server that supported IMAP and it works just fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a server-side issue. After switching to a production-grade mail server that supported IMAP, the issue was resolved.